# configurar una variable al redireccionar a otro html

Tags: javascript, html, bug

Bueno básicamente lo que estoy haciendo es después de usar el `document.location.href` quiero q cuando se cargue la pagina llame a una función que cambia el tipo a aves para que me saque por pantalla solo aves(dependiendo del tipo sale una cosa u otra)

/******ESTA ES LA FUNCION QUE CAMBIA LA CATEGORIA (SE LLAMA AS TARDE)*********/

```
 function polloCheck() {
  state.type = "aves";
  defaultStatementCategory();
}
```

/****esta es la función que redirecciona************************/

```
 function goCategoryPollo() {
      document.location.href = "categoriaAves.html";
        window.onload.polloCheck();
    }
```

Aunque ponga `windows.onload.polloCheck` para que se ejecute después de cargar, hago un `console.log(state.type)` el resultado es un string vacío. esto es lo que me devuelve `(state.type = "")` que es lo que tengo por defecto

Answer (score 0):

cuando recargas la pagina, todo se devuelve a los valores por defecto, para mantener algo debes usar cookies o variables get o post.
pero para eso necesitas lenguaje de servidor, su no lo tienes pueses usar hasting #

es la forma de pasar variables a otra pagina con js

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hash

Ejemplos:

https://www.techiedelight.com/get-hash-value-from-url-javascript/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript

Comment: lo e solucionado le paso id por la ulr para que me salga un cosa u otra pero gracias por la ayuda de todas formas